What is the difference between K8 resources springCloudGateway and gateway api?

VMware provided springCloudGateway kind resources to kubernates. Which can be defined as kind in yml config file for dynamic routing with many features.
Kubernates introduce gateway api as rules, routing, Tls termination can be configured.

But what is the difference between them?
